# Magento 2.0.7 nginx error install

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2, php-7

Good evening.
I am trying to install magento2 in my hosting and can not .. the address is : www.vapeking.com.br (Blanc page and crash )
it hangs in the installation
supports the NGINX and PHP 7 . Thank you . if you need any information please ask!

Comment: What does your PHP and NGINX error logs say?

Comment: Also, `whois` says that there's no DNS records for that URL: `% No match for domain "vapeking.com.br"`. Did you mistype it?

Answer (score 0):

Increase `max_execution_time` in PHP settings.

Answer (score 0):

try installing command line

to install command line you can use following command

```
php -d max_execution_time=18000 -d memory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:install \
--backend-frontname="admin123" \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magnento2_db \
--db-user=magnento2_user \
--db-password=magnento2_pass \
--base-url="http://magento2.emizentech.com/" \
--base-url-secure="https://magento2.emizentech.com/" \
--currency="USD" \
--use-rewrites="1" \
--admin-user="admin" \
--admin-password="admin@123!" \
--admin-email="info@emizentech.com" \
--admin-firstname="Emizen" \
--admin-lastname="Tech"
```

make sure to change parameter values

Comment: thank you dear . I managed to install the way you posted .. but he's all broken .. look there! thank you .... 
I noticed this message in administration : Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider.

Comment: this is permission issue 
you can set permission via below 2 commands : 1st:- #> chmod -R 755 ./ 
2nd :- #> chmod -R 777 var/ pub/